# Galaxy S3 mini (i8190N) stuck in boot-loop after flashing custom ROM

Tags: boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I've got a S3 Mini (i8190N) & I tried to install a custom ROM to it which failed. My phone will boot but then before the ROM/OS starts it reboots so it's stuck in a Bootloop. I cannot get into Recovery 'cause when I try that it simply just reboots. I can get into download mode! 
I'vve had enough messing about trying to find a custom ROM; I don't think there is any out there. (The one I tried was mentioned later on in the thread that it isn't compatible with the model I've got.)

Comment: So what's the actual question here?

Answer (score 0):

there could be various reasons for bootlooping like installing ROM which has size larger than your phone's HBOOT,
or a bad ROM.